# Find determinant of a 2x3 matrix to find eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Im running into problems while trying to find the eigenspaces.  Should I include the row of zeros when finding the eigenvalues? Also if yes then would that mean I include the row of zeros when finding the eigenspaces (where I have a little question mark)

Thanks for the help!

[image]

Comment: Determinants are undefined for non-square matrices.

Comment: You should not have deleted the bottom row; you should include the row of zeros.

Comment: And so are eigenvalues.  An eigevale is associated with an eigenvector, such that the product of the vector with the mateix is a scalar multiple of the vector, and that scalar multiplier is the eigenvalue.  But your matrux multiplies a vector with two components to give one with three components -- the vectors can't be scalar multiples of each other.

Answer (score 2):

keep everything a square matrix because determinants inverse and other nice things only apply to square matrices. this shows the third eigenvalue to be 0

Comment: Thanks @shai horowitz for eigenvalue = 3 , I would get three equations (x+2y+z=3x, 2x+y+z=3y, 0=z) Does that seem about right

Comment: yeah but 0=3z same but homegenous.

Comment: I was thinking 0=3z could be simplified to z=0, so I could take z out of the other two equations so that the eigenspace(for 3) =  span(y[0.5, 1,0])

Comment: there the same, it's just my preference sorry for confusing you.

Comment: ok thanks , your great!